# EditorConfig new line per parameter for function calls

Tags: c#, editorconfig

I've been trawling the docs and I don't think this exists as an option but basically I want to enforce each parameter of a function call to be on a new line.

e.g. I hate this:

```
var result = GetResult(request, startDate, endDate, myTypes,
                    false, false, pageNumber);
```

and I hate this even more (different numbers of parameters per line):

```
var result = GetResult(request, startDate, endDate, myTypes,
                    person, thing, 
                    false, false, pageNumber, penny, job, situation, context);
```

I would love an `editorconfig` entry to make the above into:

```
var result = GetResult(
    request, 
    startDate, 
    endDate, 
    myTypes,
    false, 
    false, 
    pageNumber);
```

and

```
var result = GetResult(
    request, 
    startDate, 
    endDate, 
    myTypes,
    person, 
    thing, 
    false, 
    false, 
    pageNumber, 
    penny, 
    job, 
    situation, 
    context);
```

Ideally I'd be able to specify the maximum number of parameters before it forces the above, but this is probably a pipe dream e.g. I would want 1 or 2, maybe even 3 parameters to remain on one line line below:

```
var result1 = GetResult(request);
var result2 = GetResult(request, startDate);
var result3 = GetResult(request, startDate, endDate);
//only after 3 force the rule
var result4 = GetResult(
    request, 
    startDate, 
    endDate, 
    myTypes);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of an EditorConfig-specific solution for this, but if you use Rider (or ReSharper, I'd assume), you can change the settings at `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> `C#` -> `Line Breaks and Wrapping`.

Under `Arrangement of Method Signatures`, set `Wrap formal parameters` to `Chop if long or multiline`.
Under `Arrangement of Invocations`, set `Wrap invocation arguments` to `Chop if long or multiline`.

From Rider's code style preview pane:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The property in .editorconfig is called [wrap_arguments_style](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/EditorConfig_CSHARP_LineBreaksPageSchema.html#Arrangement_of_invocations).

> Property names:﻿
> [resharper_]csharp_wrap_arguments_style, [resharper_]wrap_arguments_style
>
> Possible values:﻿
>
> wrap_if_long: Simple wrap
>
> chop_if_long: Chop if long or multiline
>
> chop_always: Chop always

I have `csharp_wrap_arguments_style=chop_if_long` in my .editorconfig, which makes ReSharper to chop parameters to own lines, if the line is too long.

You may want to set also `csharp_wrap_parameters_style`, which will do the same for method declarations. Possible values are the same for that too.

Comment: This is the right answer, I wish .editorconfig offered something similar for python!

Answer (score 1):

Use `max_line_length`, documented [here](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#max_line_length). Does what you want, but only indirectly, by contracting lines of length longer than this value. Set the value to something like `80`.

Note: the analogous option for Prettier [is](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width) `printWidth`.